# How to trigger before INSERT statement in stored procedure in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I read this [Help with SQL Server Trigger to truncate bad data before insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102288/help-with-sql-server-trigger-to-truncate-bad-data-before-insert) but not solve my issue when is about stored procedure.

**update**

Because of my issue [Why cannot create global temporary table or truncate it when call a stored procedure from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407728/why-cannot-create-global-temporary-table-or-truncate-it-when-call-a-stored-proce) when truncate table from stored procedure when it is called from C# code.

**end update**

The stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aProcedure]
  @val1 VARCHAR(255),
  @val2 VARCHAR(255),
  ...
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT @sql = '//Do SELECT statement'

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(....)

    SELECT @paramList = ' /*list of parameters*/';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramList, ... parameters
END
```

And the trigger I used (I'm beginner in SQL)

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE dbo.MyTable
END
```

How do trigger, **when from stored procedure the values are inserted into `dbo.MyTable`**, which truncate my table first and after that make `INSERT` operation ?

I read the documentation from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38808/Overview-of-SQL-Server-database-Triggers).

Thank you

Comment: Wow - truncating the table in an insert trigger should cause many lulz with your colleagues, but is a good example why triggers should be regarded as a last resort.

Comment: @nonnb: Read my updated question.

Comment: Have you not noticed that you seem to be piling broken solutions on top of broken solutions? As I recommended on a previous question, maybe you need to take a step back and look at the overall problem you're dealing with (instead of the current problem with the *solution* you've decided upon) and see if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: I didn't found better way than using trigger, I guess is a good one. I didn't use nested stored procedure !

Comment: Most SQL Server developers will *rarely*, if ever, use Global temp tables. Trigger's aren't that common, and `TRUNCATE` is quite rare too, in my experience. So far, your "solution" is using all 3 of these.

Comment: It is possible that stored procedure called from C# code to not have rights over tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the stored procedure itself truncate the table. **No need to write a trigger**. 
Trigger will slow down your process

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aProcedure]
  @val1 VARCHAR(255),
  @val2 VARCHAR(255),
  ...
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT @sql = '//Do SELECT statement'

     TRUNCATE table  dbo.MyTable -- < add truncate here
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(....)

    SELECT @paramList = ' /*list of parameters*/';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramList, ... parameters
END
```

Comment: I know it but i need for my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407728/why-cannot-create-global-temporary-table-or-truncate-it-when-call-a-stored-proce

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE dbo.MyTable
END
```